Bruno OAuth2 config
I am trying to automate api testing through Azure DevOps pipelines, and have set up some bruno configuration that does not seem to work. the OAuth2 is set up with an application registration in Azure EntraID. This is my bruno configuration:
collection.bru
auth {
  mode: oauth2
}

auth:oauth2 {
  grant_type: client_credentials
  access_token_url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/v2.0/token
  client_id: ***
  client_secret: ***
  scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
}

script:post-response {
  var token = res.body.access_token;
  console.log(res.body)
  console.log('Access Token:', token);  // Debug log
  if (token) {
    bru.setVar('oauth2_token', token)
  } else {
    console.log('Token retrieval failed.');  // Log if token isn't retrieved
  }
}

test.bru
meta {
  name: Backend Api Test
  type: http
  seq: 2
}

get {
  url: https://my-app.com/api
  body: none
  auth: oauth2
}

This configuration does not seem to work in my pipeline, nor when testing it locally. I am getting a 401 Unauthorized errro. However, when i run this request from bruno desktop, i am getting a 200 response and it works as expected. The output from the run looks like this:
Backend (401 Unauthorized) - 205 ms
{}
Access Token: undefined
Token retrieval failed.

What am i doing wrong here? It seems as when i run it locally outside of bruno desktop and in a pipeline, it does not work. Any help is appreciated.
